# Null coalescing operator with bool

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert som Objective-C code to swift and I have the following statement which I am stuck with.

How would I convert:

```
self.viewController.view.alpha = !self.viewDisabled ?: 0;
```

To swift?

```
viewController.view.alpha = !self.viewDisabled ?? 0
```

The null coalescing operator in Swift dosen't seem to work as I get an *"Binary Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'"* error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, in your Objective-C example, the use of `?:` is completely unnecessary. `!self.viewDisabled ?: 0` is the same as just `!self.viewDisabled`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) has nothing to do with boolean values.

Use the full form ternary operator:

```
viewController.view.alpha = viewDisabled ? 0 : 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Nil coalescing is used for optional variable. As specified in the document, the nil coalescing corresponds to:

```
a != nil ? a! : b    //if a has value, return unwrapped value of a, else return b
```

Consider those examples:

```
var optionalBoolean : Bool? //don't have value (or == nil)
var falseBoolean : Bool = false

var a = optionalBoolean ?? true //return true cause optionalBoolean does not have value, so it return 'true'
var b = falseBoolean ?? true //return false cause falseBoolean has value = false.
```

Comment: It's kind of weird that you can do `var b = falseBoolean ?? true` but can't do `var c = falseBoolean != nil ? falseBoolean! : true` when apple says "`a ?? b` is a shorthand for `a != nil ? a! : b`" though.

Comment: You can't. Because falseBoolean is not an optional variable. You cannot compare it to nil.

Comment: Why can you `var b = falseBoolean ?? true` then?

Comment: Ah, I missed understand your answer. I think that Apple make an exception that allow non-optional (so non-nil) variable with ??. However, when you do the comparison of A to B, A must be comparable to B. It mean, A must be a same kind of object as B, or A must be convertible to B.